# How to get number of days between the earliest date and the oldest date in every row of my input

Tags: oracle, date, analytic-functions

I am having difficulty getting the number of days between the oldest date and the newest date, the problem I have is if I use `MIN` or `MAX` I have to group by a column which is an issue as I do not have a column to group by.

If my data looks like this:

```
 2017/01/01         EXAMPLE 
 2017/01/01         EXAMPLE
 2017/01/01         EXAMPLE
 2017/01/05         EXAMPLE
 2017/01/06         EXAMPLE
 2017/01/06         EXAMPLE
 2017/01/08         EXAMPLE
```

I need to add a column with a static number throughout the table so it looks like:

```
 2017/01/01         EXAMPLE       8
 2017/01/01         EXAMPLE       8
 2017/01/01         EXAMPLE       8
 2017/01/05         EXAMPLE       8
 2017/01/06         EXAMPLE       8
 2017/01/06         EXAMPLE       8
 2017/01/08         EXAMPLE       8
```

This is probably very simple but I just cannot get it right without grouping - 8 is the number of days between the earliest day and the last day

This is for ORACLE

Comment: What is "EXAMPLE"  Is your example data two columns?  Please clarify.

Answer (score 3):

Use `max()` and `min()` in analytic version:

```
select dt, str, max(dt) over () - min(dt) over () + 1 diff
  from t
```

Example:

```
with t (dt, str) as (
    select date '2017-01-01', 'EXAMPLE' from dual union all
    select date '2017-01-01', 'EXAMPLE' from dual union all
    select date '2017-01-01', 'EXAMPLE' from dual union all
    select date '2017-01-05', 'EXAMPLE' from dual union all
    select date '2017-01-06', 'EXAMPLE' from dual union all
    select date '2017-01-06', 'EXAMPLE' from dual union all
    select date '2017-01-08', 'EXAMPLE' from dual)
select dt, str, max(dt) over () - min(dt) over () + 1 diff
  from t
```

Result:

```
DT          STR           DIFF
----------- ------- ----------
2017-01-01  EXAMPLE          8
2017-01-01  EXAMPLE          8
2017-01-01  EXAMPLE          8
2017-01-05  EXAMPLE          8
2017-01-06  EXAMPLE          8
2017-01-06  EXAMPLE          8
2017-01-08  EXAMPLE          8
7 rows selected
```

---

Edit:
Your query should be:

```
select RATE_CODE, BUSINESS_DATE, 
       max(BUSINESS_DATE) over () - min(BUSINESS_DATE) over () + 1 diff 
  from RATE_CODE_STAT_DAILY
```

You don't need `with` clause, I added it only to make some example data. Just use query above. And I didn't know real table name and column names.

In this case you should use `min` and `max`. `First_value` and `last_value` are alternative, but please read carefully documentation and understand difference.

Comment: with RATE_CODE_STAT_DAILY (RATE_CODE, BUSINESS_DATE) as (
select 
RATE_CODE,
BUSINESS_DATE
from dual 
)
select RATE_CODE, BUSINESS_DATE, max(BUSINESS_DATE) over () - min(BUSINESS_DATE) over () + 1 diff
from RATE_CODE_STAT_DAILY

Comment: Hi Ponder, Thanks very much for the above, I am having difficulty as my SQLDeveloper is kicking out errors saying invalid identifier on RATE_CODE after the Select from the above query

Answer (score 0):

The below gave me exactly what I need - thank you @ponder for the hints on analytic, did some research and came across FIRST_VALUE and LAST_VALUE

```
select 
RATE_CODE,
BUSINESS_DATE,
FIRST_VALUE(BUSINESS_DATE) over() AS FIRSTDATE,
LAST_VALUE(BUSINESS_DATE) over(ORDER BY RATE_CODE RANGE BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING) AS LASTDATE

from RATE_CODE_STAT_DAILY
where BUSINESS_DATE > '01-JUL-17'
```

Comment: I think You should use `min` and `max`. The query you attached in comments does not work because `dual` has not columns like `rate_code`. Simply replace `first_value` with `min` and last_value with `max` in your answer and work on real table. But if You insist on `first_value` and it works for You it's OK. For me it looks somewhat suspicious.